# can the empty set contain itself?

Tags: calculus

This question may sound weird but anyway here it goes. Is the following equation true?
$$\emptyset = \{ \emptyset \}$$

The reason I think it is not true:

- The empty set is an element by itself, therefore the R.H.S contains one element.  But due to L.H.S, the amount of elements of the R.H.S must be $0$.

The reason I think it is true:

- The empty set is a subset of every set. Therefore, the emptyset on the R.H.S must be a subset of the L.H.S. In other words, we have the following relation: $\emptyset \supseteq \{ \emptyset \} \Rightarrow \emptyset = \{ \emptyset \}$.

Comment: No, it is not true.

Comment: The empty set is **empty** i.e. has no elements.

Comment: No, it's not true; the empty set is an element of the right hand side, but not of the left hand side. Being an element is not the same as being a subset.

Comment: (Put another way: is an empty bag the same thing as a bag that contains an empty bag inside?)

Comment: I did search after this question before I did poste it. Sorry for dublicate @MauroALLEGRANZA.

Comment: You have to separete $\in$ (is an element of) from $\subseteq$ (is a subset of). You have to use "contain" as a synonym of one of the two, but not both.

Comment: Indeed. "contain" (or I think "include") is typically used for $\supseteq$, or "owns" for $\owns$.

Answer (score 0):

The empty set contains itself but the empty set is not an element of itself. The set whose only element is the empty set is not the empty set.